# Improving Backup Performance using SQL native methodology

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup

I am trying to gather some stats on comparison of run time vs performance between Litespeed backups and sql native backups. As we are no longer going to use Lite Speed [even though i personally loved that SW], have to gather metrics how SQL will perform using native compression backup]

So i am looking for a way to reduce CPU usage to X % while taking native compression backups. In Litespeed we just specified this option in advanced tabs and saw everything running fine. I am aware of resource governor, but due to some constraints not able to use it. Will need to work on that. But is there a better and smarter way to do this. Please suggest

Edit.. Have to add, as per security and company policies we cannot use third party or external SP's to be created. I saw this can be achieved using OLa 's script as well, but we wont get approvals to introduce this :(

Comment: Throttle in Ola's scripts is only valid if you are using LITESPEED anyways.

Comment: I blogged about this topic [here](http://sqlworldwide.com/optimize-sql-backup/).

Comment: @SqlWorldWide, thanks for the article, but i am looking on how to throttle CPU value because other process fails when backup uses all 100 % cpu

Comment: How about you use compression along with buffercount and maxtransfersize .. do a trial and error approach and go with the numbers that look more promising in your env.

Comment: @Kin, thanks . i am definitely testing that as well. However the problem is such that we have to throttle CPU as this being one of the busiest system we have with TB's of database. We have over 512 GB's of RAM and more than 128 Logical processors but apps are such that if backup eats up 100 5 of CPU they tend to slow down. so was looking a native way of throttling this down

Comment: Have you considered resource governor?

Comment: @SqlWorldWide, yes as i wrote above, tried and seems no luck. looking for alternative way

Comment: What type of SQL Server backups is it that consumes 100% of the 5 of your 128 logical CPUs? Are these full DB backups of 50 DBs running at the same time, are these log backups of 100 DBs running one after the other, etc.? Wonder if simply staggering or lightening the concurrent load would help the issue? Do your DB and app server use the same physical resources or are the apps on separate physical resources than the DB server. Does the app response time bog down when the 5 logical processes on the SQL Server uses 100% of 5 of those or does the CPU utilization spike also affect the web server?

Answer (score 1):

Resource Governor can control the resource consumption of a backup.

> By default, backing up using compression significantly increases CPU
> usage, and the additional CPU consumed by the compression process can
> adversely impact concurrent operations. Therefore, you might want to
> create a low-priority compressed backup in a session whose CPU usage
> is limited byResource Governor when CPU contention occurs. This topic
> presents a scenario that classifies the sessions of a particular SQL
> Server user by mapping them to a Resource Governor workload group that
> limits CPU usage in such cases.

[Use Resource Governor to Limit CPU Usage by Backup Compression (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/use-resource-governor-to-limit-cpu-usage-by-backup-compression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is third party but it's free and powerful.   I would check out Http://[Dbatools.io](https://dbatools.io/functions/backup-dbadatabase/)

In addition you can specify buffer size, number of files (Striping). Etc.  definitely worth a look.

Comment: Almost every parameter/option offered by `Backup-DbaDatabase` in `dbatools` is available via the native `Backup database` T-SQL. Using `dbatools` here isn't really necessary, it'll just be acting as a different front-end. I'm a huge advocate for `dbatools` but it's not needed to address the OP's optimization goals.